# How add personal list for all users

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, external-list

I want to integrate Sharepoint with my external system. Sharepoint should load tasks from my system and show them in the list on user personal page. Integration should be done using Sharepoint client-object-model.

Is that possible, to add lists to all users on their personal page with my external tasks?